# Python strip function

Tags: python

## In python when I try this :-

```
ac = "Pearl Riverb-Vaccines"
b = ac.strip("-Vaccines")
b = b.strip()
print(b)
```

## The output is :- Pearl Riverb

## But when I try this :-

```
ac = "Pearl Rivera-Vaccines"
b = ac.strip("-Vaccines")
b = b.strip()
print(b)
```

## The output is :- Pearl River

So why is the 'a' missing in the second code?
I have tried every other letter and it is printing but what is the problem with letter 'a' ?

Answer (score 6):

`strip()` does not respect count or order when it removes characters from the end of your string. The argument you passed it, `"-Vaccines"`, contains an "a", so it will remove the "a" from "Rivera". It does not matter that it already removed an "a" from "Vaccines" and it does not matter that it doesn't come between a V and a c.

Consider another example:

```
>>> "abcXqrqqqrrrqrqrqrqrqqrr".strip("qr")
'abcX'
```

Many `q`s and `r`s are removed here, even though the argument to `strip` contains only one of each.

In general, `strip` is not suitable for removing a static number of characters from the end of a string. One possible alternative is to use regex, which can match a literal character sequence that appears at the end of a string:

```
>>> import re
>>> ac = "Pearl Rivera-Vaccines"
>>> re.sub("-Vaccines$", "", ac)
'Pearl Rivera'
```

---

In his answer, Tom Karzes observes that this approach doesn't readily work on strings that contain characters that have special meanings in a regex. For instance,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo^bar"
>>> re.sub("^bar$", "", s)
'foo^bar'
```

`^` has a special meaning in regex, so the pattern `"^bar$"` fails to match the end of the string `s`. If the string you want to match contains special characters, you should escape it, either manually or with an `re.escape` call.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo^bar"
>>> re.sub(r"\^bar$", "", s)
'foo'
>>> re.sub(re.escape("^bar") + "$", "", s)
'foo'
```

Comment: Hi Kevin thank you for your explanation and solution provided, but why is the 'a' in Pearl is not removed?

Comment: Because strip only removes the trailing characters @SandeepVarma see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the argument to `strip` isn't used the way you think it is.  The argument isn't treated as a sequence of characters, but rather as a set of characters.  Any character in the argument string is removed.  For example:

```
"abaca".strip("ac")
```

Produces:

```
'b'
```

since all instances of `"a"` and `"b"` have been removed.

If you just want to remove a suffix from a string, you can do something like:

```
ac = "Pearl Rivera-Vaccines"
s = "-Vaccines"
b = ac
if b.endswith(s):
    b = b[:-len(s)]
```

This will result in `b` having the value:

```
'Pearl Rivera'
```

Note that this will be faster than using the `re` module.  It will also be more flexible, since it will work with any non-empty string (whereas creating a regular expression will require escaping certain characters).